# .Net RegEx specific example

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have pretty large file names that follow a standard naming practice and I am attempting to write a RegEx to match them.

When you are reading the file name it follows the convention:

p_d(set of 8 numeric)_t(set of 8numeric)*images.ext*(any# of alphanumeric)

**For example:**
p_d12345678_t12345678_images.ext_0

the few I attempted brought back unrecognized escape sequence OR no matches found. For example this one brings back no matches:

```
fileInfo = value 
'that changes depending on what file I'm looking for 

RegEx("\bp\b_\bd\d*\b_\bt" & fileInfo & "\d*\b_images\\.\bext_\w*")
```

Does something like this work or am I just doing it wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: `\b` stands for word boundary,, underscores (`_`) are valid word characters, there are no boundaries around them..

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial 
talks about \b if you want exact match on something..
I appreciate the help but none of you addressed the fact that I need to insert a value from fileInfo into the regex.

Comment: `a\b_a` won't match `"a_a"` just like `a\baa` won't match `"aaa"` - how long **fileInfo** can be - is it already a string containing 8 digits?

Comment: Where does fileinfo come from? I presume it is a string variable initialized somewhere above. Do you need to extract the substrings in "_"?

Comment: is my updated answer closer to what you need or are we still missing something? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** to include the **fileInfo** String object of 0-8 characters + to match the new specification:

```
"\bp_d\d{8}_t" & fileInfo & "\d{" & 8 - fileInfo.Length() & "}_images\.ext\w*\b"
```

Comment: Thanks!..this looks like it will work perfectly. I appreciate your help

Comment: also-  one last question... to work correctly the . has to be like this, right? \\.

Comment: uhh,, not in the regex - but if the vb.net uses \ to excape characters than all of the \ should be \\, not just before the dot

Comment: Gotcha. wow, you were a great help! i would vote up if i could!!

Answer (score 0):

So the sample is:

```
p_d12345678_t12345678_images.ext_0
```

The pattern then shoud be:

```
"p_d\d{1,8}_t\d{1,8}_images\.ext_0"
```

Why are you using all the \b escapes?

Comment: there is a specification before the example

Answer (score 0):

```
p_d(\w){8}_t(\w){8}_images.ext_(\w){1}
```

Matches the sample that you've provided - I'm using \w instead of \d because you've suggested that the 8 characters are alphanumeric, if they're just digits then you could change them to \d

Tested here: http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=p_d(%5Cw)%7B8%7D_t(%5Cw)%7B8%7D_images.ext_(%5Cw)%7B1%7D&input=p_d12345678_t12345678_images.ext_0

Comment: they are just digits, sorry I edited that.  the problem is the value i need to insert..